Difficulty Scrolling WebView Content Within a NestedScrollView
Problem
I'm encountering an issue with scrolling in my Android XML layout that includes a NestedScrollView and a ConstraintLayout. Despite configuring the NestedScrollView to allow scrolling when the content exceeds the screen size, the scrolling behavior doesn't seem to work as expected inside the WebView.
Here's my XML layout file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/topContainer"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_phone_input_container"
            android:focusable="true">

          

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_270sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideEnd"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.619"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideStart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/step5img"
                tools:ignore="WebViewLayout">
            </WebView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>


Despite setting fillViewport="true" and android:fitsSystemWindows="true", the scrolling behavior doesn't seem to work as expected. Particularly, the WebView inside the ConstraintLayout cannot be scrolled.
I've confirmed that the content inside the ConstraintLayout exceeds the screen size, and I can scroll through the entire content. However, I'm encountering difficulty scrolling through the content within the WebView.
Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Can you try to remove NestedScrollView. I don't need such a thing in my own project.
just add
settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

